# Gatling Load test with Pareto principle on input feed

Tags: gatling

I'm using [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) to load test a GET endpoint.

```
.../catByName?name=XYZ
```

In order to [feed](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/) the load test with cat names, I have a CSV with the names.

Currently, there are four options to read the names from the file: Queue, Random, Shuffle, and Circular.

I like to better simulate real-life scenarios, that behave according to the long-tail and [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle).

So I like that 20% of the names will be used in 80% of the requests and the other 80% of Names will be used in 20% of the requests.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 different feeders, one 4 times larger than the other one and a [randomSwitch](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario#randomswitch) with 80/20 ratios.